# Can't find the example projects from Stanford cs193p

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cs193p

I am looking for the Flickr multithreaded example application that is used in lecture 10 "Performance and Threading". He does a few things that I would like to look at. The particular files I'm looking for are ImageLoadingOperation.h and MyTableViewController.m?

Does anybody know if they exist somewhere out there and I just missed it? If they don't exist, does anybody know where some good examples of using NSInvocationOperation and creating a class to do loading of images in a threaded manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/downloads/10-ThreadedFlickrTableView.zip

http://cs193p.stanford.edu/

Comment: Wow, I feel foolish. I guess I must have just missed it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, everyone has those moments. Glad to help!